# How do I process a bitmap in a background thread in Android?

Tags: android, background-thread

I created an Android application where I can process the filter to a bitmap in the `onCreate` method of the layout. However, I want to filter the bitmap in another thread instead of the UI thread.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html may work for your case

Answer (score 1):

Use an async task for the same
Let's say your global bitmap which you are displaying is mBitmap, tempbitmap on which you will do the processing is mBitmapTemp,

```
class EditActionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {    

    @Override 
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {           
            int position = params[0];
            Bitmap mBitmapTemp= mBitmap.copy(mBitmap.getConfig(), true);
            Bitmap bitmap  = ; // do your editing
            return bitmap;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // update ui from result butmap         
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
EditActionTask editActionTask = new EditActionTask();
editActionTask.execute();
```